# ¿ Cómo cambiar mi columna al tipo de dato Serial para que sea autoincremental en Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

En Postgresql, tengo una `tabla authors` donde ya tengo data grabada, esta tabla tiene dos columnas:`id(type integer), name`.
el **id** esta como `primary key`, y a su vez en otra tabla esta como `foreign key`. necesito cambiar el id a `autoincremental` sin perder los datos, como puedo hacer?
Probé hacer esto:

```html
ALTER TABLE authors
ALTER COLUMN id_author TYPE serial;
```

Pero muestra este error:

**ERROR:  no existe el tipo «serial»
SQL state: 42704**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que como lo dice la documentación [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> Los tipos de datos smallserial, serial y bigserial no son tipos
> verdaderos

Por lo que en realidad si le haces una descripción a la tabla

postgres=# \d authors

Te darás cuenta que se dio de alta un integer (incluso si tu lo hubieras hecho con un tipo de datos serial), para poder "convertirlo" o mas bien simular que este sea de tipo sería solo crea una secuencia, si quieres incluso con la misma nomenclatura que utiliza PostgreSQL, por ejemplo:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE authors_id_author_seq;
```

Que es el equivalente a **tabla_nombrecampo_seq** ahora seteale el maximo de los valores de la tabla actual para que comience a partir de ese numero por ejemplo:

```
SELECT MAX(id_author) FROM author;
SELECT setval('authors_id_author_seq', 10000); -- pensando que sea 10000 el resultado de la consulta de arriba
```

Después solo sería colocar el nextval como default con algo como esto:

```
ALTER TABLE author ALTER COLUMN id_author SET DEFAULT nextval('authors_id_author_seq'::regclass);
```

Y de esta forma debería de funcionar.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474720/alter-data-type-of-a-column-to-serial